# How to darken an image on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, css

**My problem..**

I have a number of images (inside hyperlinks), and I want each to darken on mouseover (i.e. apply a black mask with high opacity or something), and then go back to normal on mouseout . But I can't figure out the best way to do it.

**I've tried..**

- Jquery color animate and some javascript references.
- Setting the opacity of the image with javascript.

**I don't want..**

- Image start at 80% opacity then go to 100% on mouseover (that's easy).
- To swap between 2 images (one light & one dark), forgot the mention this sorry..

**To reiterate..**

I want in image (inslide a hyperlink) to darken on mouseover and then lose its darkness on mouseout.

Thoughts?

**UPDATE :**

This is my progress from suggestions. Looks fine in IE8, but not in FF3

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" style="background-color:black; opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100)">
            <img src="http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_uk/images/logo.gif" width="200" 
            style="opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100)" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100" 
            onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.6;this.filters.alpha.opacity=60" />
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thoughts?

-- Lee

**ANSWER**

I'm going with this (seems to work in IE8 & FF)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

        .outerLink 
        {
            background-color:black; 
            display:block; 
            opacity:1;
            filter:alpha(opacity=100);
            width:200px;
        }

        img.darkableImage 
        {
            opacity:1;
            filter:alpha(opacity=100);
        }
</style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" class="outerLink">
            <img src="http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_uk/images/logo.gif" width="200" 
            class="darkableImage" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100" 
            onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.6;this.filters.alpha.opacity=60" />
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there an option to have 2 different images, one light and one dark?

Comment: Dorry Malphas, I forgot to mention in my question that I didn;t want to di it this way, cheers though

Comment: It might be that if your "tried it, didn't work" (9_9 don't you think you could provide more information about what you tried exactly and what happened?) scenarios didn't work, they'd work if your link and image elements are set to CSS `display: block` rather than their default `display: inline`. The default setting can restrict some of the effects in question to the line-height of the inline elements.

Comment: Thanks eyelidlessness. block:inline helped with the code in my question. :-)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Or, similar to erikkallen's idea, make the background of the A tag black, and make the image semitransparent on mouseover. That way you won't have to create additional divs.

- [CSS Only Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Dfpm/) (will only work in modern browsers)
- [JavaScript based Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gTcym/1/) (will [probably] work in all common browsers)

---

Source for the CSS-based solution:

```
a.darken {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    padding: 0;
}

a.darken img {
    display: block;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
            transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

a.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0.7;

}
```

And the image:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="darken">
    <img src="http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg" width="200">
</a>
```

Comment: This definitely does work. "Didn't work" is not a very useful problem description, so please come up with something more specific or nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Apologies x3ro (and all), i'll try to be more descriptive in future ;-)

Comment: This works great but I have images that have different shapes. So the square images look great but ones with rounded edges have the black background showing. Is there any way to hide this?

Comment: @Nick: I really can't think of a good way using pure CSS. If you we're willing to use lots of JavaScript, you could theoretically use a canvas that has the same opacity values than the image you are displaying (by iterating through all pixels of the image) and use that canvas as background of the images. This will work okay if you have a single shape for many images, but it will fail miserably (performance wise) if every image has a different shape (haven't tested though, just guessing)

Comment: @Nick I know its late but for shapes: create a silhouette of the image (e.g with Photoshop) and use that for the background: http://jsfiddle.net/4Dfpm/

Comment: @fresskoma You've made my day.

Comment: Nowadays you can just use filter: brightness(80%) contrast(130%); on the hover element, this works for circle / odd cut images with transparent backgrounds

Answer (score 11):

Make the image 100% bright so it is clear.
And then on Img hover reduce it to whatever brightness you want.

```css
img {
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
   transition: all 1s ease;
}

img:hover {
   -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
   filter: brightness(70%);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x150/ebebeb/000.jpg">
```

That will do it,
Hope that helps

Comment: You should move the transitions to `img {}`, then you do not have to add `filter: brightness(100%)`.

Answer (score 5):

I realise this is a little late but you could add the following to your code. This won't work for transparent pngs though, you'd need a cropping mask for that. Which I'm now going to see about.

```
outerLink {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

outerLink:hover:after {
    background: #000;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this...

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.frame { background-color: #000; }
    img.pic:hover {
      opacity: .6;
      filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    }
</style>

<div class="frame">
    <img class="pic" src="path/to/image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ei this seems to work fine in FF but not IE8. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do it with Jquery, you will get a solution that works cross browser in almost every browser out there. `$('#id_of_div').css('opacity',.6);`

Answer (score 2):

Put a black, semitransparent, div on top of it.

Comment: Tried, it didn't work. If you get it working this way, please let me know.

Comment: How do you make it transparent? It needs some tweaking to get right cross-browser (which jQuery will do for you).

Answer (score 1):

Create black png with lets say 50% transparency. Overlay this on mouseover.