# Darken image on rollover

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have a list of images that need to darken on rollover. I would REALLY love to do this without a bloated css rollover technique as anytime spent out of photoshop makes me very happy. I got part of the way there but something is going wrong. Here it is live:

http://daveywhitney.com/dark/

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Darken</title>
<style type="text/css">
#topnav {
    float:left;
    margin:22px 0 0 50px;
    list-style:none;
}
.kitchy {
    background-color:#000000;
    width:112px;
    height:203px;
}

#topnav  a:hover{
    opacity:.6;
}

#topnav  li {
    display:inline;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="topnav">
            <li class="kitchy"><a href="#"><img src="img/kitch.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><img src="img/deck_small.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/door_small.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/lumber_small.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/tools_small.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/paint_small.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How is this:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/T5Fy9/2/)**

What I changed:

`<ul>` and `<li>` to `<div>`. Added `kitchy` class to all menu items,

Changed this CSS:

```
#topnav {
    float:left;
    margin:22px 0 0 50px;
    list-style:none;
}
.kitchy {
    background: #000;
    width:112px;
    height:103px;
    float:left;
    margin:5px; /*Optional*/
}

#topnav  a:hover{
    opacity:.5;
}
```

Comment: Nice! This is just what I was looking for. Looks like display inline was causing the trouble. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for :
[How to darken an image on mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747637/how-to-darken-an-image-on-mouseover)

Comment: Yea I had looked that over earlier but it didn't quite get me where I need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Dont set the width, height, for the `li`, and don't set it to inline, instead use `float: left`.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/x9M2N/1/