# Darkening a rounded image using either CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

all of the solutions I've seen thus far to darken an image are for images that do not have rounded corners. This is problematic because all of the solutions I've seen call for using background color. When the corners are rounded the background color shows through. I'm talking about these solutions:

http://jsbin.com/icemiy/1/edit

[Darken image on rollover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249229/darken-image-on-rollover)

Are there other ways of doing this that are still purely through css or javascript (jQuery included, of course). Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: not any that I know. You can achieve this by javascript. In `CSS` you can use `divs` to achieve the rounded corners effect with tint.

Comment: on the first link you provided, if you set a border-radius on both the `.tint` class and the images, it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using this tutorial http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/hover-zoom-effect-with-jquery-and-css/

Hopefully people trying to do this same thing will find this page and one of these several solutions will work for them!

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/L7rWJ/

Doable entirely with css.

round both the overlay and the image:

```
#overlay, img{
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
     border-radius:15px;
}
```

Oh, and if you don't care about ie you can use transitions for extra niceness: http://jsfiddle.net/fYEWr/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `background-clip` on images and their containers -[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/icemiy/121/edit)

```
  figure {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding; 
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; 
    background-clip: padding-box;
  }

  img {
    float: left;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity .3s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s linear;
    transition: opacity .3s linear;

    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding; 
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; 
    background-clip: padding-box;
  }
```

Comment: adding border-radius only to figure will do work, you don't need img border-radius. but comparing to other answers your is corect :) +1

Comment: @MilanJaric nope :) it won't work without the img border-radius - http://jsbin.com/icemiy/129/edit

Comment: @ZoltanToth I've attempted your method and it is improving, however I get a large amount of spill over from the color, even though my code is identical (I think) to the example). Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: @ZoltanToth hmm this is super strange. Your example works perfectly, however, it turns my image white instead of black...I know that #000 is black so I have no idea why this is happening....added another photo.

Comment: @ZoltanToth Also, is there a way to dynamically set the width of #figure? Currently we are hardcoding it to 200px.

Comment: replace width: 200px; with disply: inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

Add border radius to the container for which you are giving background-color.

In your jsBin example do:

```
  .tint {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you  can put this code in img, img hover and tint to have rounded corner

```
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
```