# How to change a lot of img when hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I am a new web developer so I don't know best practices.

I have a few images on the page which i want to change on hover. I found two solutions but I dont know which is better.

First one in HTML:

```
<td>
  <a href="getContent('unlight');">
    <img src="res/images/unlight/p_first.png"
         onmouseover="this.src='res/images/light/p_first.png'" alt="First"
         onmouseout="this.src='res/images/unlight/p_first.png'"/>
    <br>first
  </a>
</td>
```

And second one using CSS:

```
<td id="first" onclick="getContent('first');">First</td>

#first{
    background: no-repeat url("./images/unlight/p_first.png");
    width: 78px;
    height: 78px;
    }

#first:hover {
    background: no-repeat url("./images/light/p_first.png");
    width: 78px;
    height: 78px;
}
```

Now for every img I need write two paths.

Can this be automated? How to do it professional and universal?

Comment: You can hover the image using css, no javascript is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a great time to get some exposure to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). You can basically write a more dynamic way of accomplishing what you want, similar to what you're currently doing in the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attributes. Plus jQuery allows you to get this kind of logic out of the HTML markup and into an entirely separate `.js` file.

Once you get jQuery included, you can create a script that looks something like this. (I've tried commenting heavily so you can understand what's going on:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Any `img` tag with a class of `some-class` (or whatever you want) will get this behavior on hover
    $("img.some-class").hover(
        // This first handler is for the `onmouseover` state
        function() {
            // Storing a query for `this` in a variable only runs the query once. Otherwise, you'd run it twice in the line below
            var $this = $(this);
            // Replace `/light/` in the image URL with `/unlight/`
            $this.attr("src", $this.replace("/light/", "unlight"));
        },
        // This second handler is for the `onmouseout` state
        // Its logic is similar to the first handler, so I'll omit comments explaining it
        function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.attr("src", $this.replace("/unlight/", "light"));
        }
    );
});
```

Now you should be able to store the `light` and `unlight` versions of each image in `light` and `unlight` subfolders. Make sure both images have the same filename. Then add `class="some-class"` to the `img` tags that you want to have this behavior.

Extra reading:

- [jQuery `hover()` method](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)
- [jQuery `attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [JavaScript `replace()` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about this resolve, but i wasnt sure it is "professional" method. It is often using solution in this problem?

Comment: It depends on the situation. I think this makes sense in your case because you have so many images that need this treatment. @Billy Moat's solution makes sense if all images are the exact same size, though I better like having an actual `<img>` tag on the page rather than a bunch of `<div>`s with background images. There are also other CSS-based solutions described on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249229/darken-image-on-rollover (I actually may like the CSS-based solution better.)

Answer (score 1):

Use can use second thing but the html should in right value. Only `td` value is not enough.

```
 <div id="first" >First</div>​
```

Dome is here http://jsfiddle.net/4qQPL/1/

Comment: It is still problem because for all images i need creat new style. Imagine that i need create 50 images. Then it is not practise.

Comment: means, multiple image display when hover on single image with in the height and width?

Comment: means one image hover change this image. Like button. But i have 50 buttons.

Comment: means, you hover on one button image, the 49 images but will be changed in to first btn image. right?

Comment: every button have itself hover-img. Every button is independent. You know what I mean?

Comment: i edited some thing. i hope this may be helpful to you. http://jsfiddle.net/4qQPL/3/

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously quite a few ways to this but here's one way.

Combine your two images into one image, use that image as the background image and on hover/focus change the background position of your image to show the second image.

Also unless you are displaying tabular data then you really shouldn't use tables on your websites. Stick with DIV tags, SECTION tags etc.

Example:

```
<a id="image1" class="hover-image" href="#">First</a>

// set a class which contains global settings for all relevant images.

a.hover-image {
 width:XXXpx;
 height:XXXpx;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:0 0;
}

a.hover-image:hover, a.hover-image:focus {
 background-position:XXXpx XXXpx;
}


// set the background image path based on a unique ID.

a#image1 {
 background-image:url(XXX.png);
}
```

Comment: Yes. but problem is that when i have 50 images. I need for all create style. I am too lazy to do this :D I was think about some script?

Answer (score -1):

**css**

```
.myButtonLink {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url('/path/to/myImage.png') bottom;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
.myButtonLink:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="myButtonLink" href="#LinkURL">Leaf</a>
```

Comment: but that will be one img. I have few different img for example:
<a href="test.html"><img src="a.jpg"/></a>
<a href="test.html"><img src="b.jpg"/></a>
<a href="test.html"><img src="c.jpg"/></a>

Comment: <td id="kancelaria" onclick="getContent('main');">kancelaria</td>
<td id="intencje" onclick="getCcontent('intencje');"></td>
<td id="ogloszenia" onclick="getContent('ogloszenia');"><br>ogĹ‚oszenia</td>
<td id="duszpasterze" onclick="getContent('duszpasterze');"><br>duszpasterstwo</td>

and CSS 

#kancelaria {
background: no-repeat url("./images/niepodswietlone/p_kancelaria.png");
width: 78px;
height: 78px;  
}

#kancelaria:hover{
background: no-repeat url("./images/podswietlone/p_kancelaria.png");
width: 78px;
height: 78px;
}

Now it is like this, but i want more universal