# jquery java script image shade

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image and I want to restrict the clickable area on this image. I want user to click only particular area.  I want to obtain a darker view out side of this clickable area. How could I achieve this usin java script and/or jquery.
Kind regards

Comment: Do you want to do a specific shape? or can you use regular boxes?

Comment: just boxes. actually only one box to determine the clicable area.

Comment: The clickable areas, that's just an `<map>`. For the darkened parts, be creative with any image editor, or take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249229/darken-image-on-rollover).

Comment: image editor will not work for me. Becouse I have to render it dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to implement the clickable area:
using image map :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map

Take a look at this website : http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

or using divs and z-index.

Comment: I managed to get position clicked point. I'll ignore clicked point out of allowed box. I want to show image darker out of the clickable area.

Comment: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/ Thank you! This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can follow what have been in the link using developer tool or firebug (f12) and then inspect and discover how they are doing it.
This is the link for documentation [http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html)
Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be difficult, but if you use a  to determine a clickable area first, you can use jquery to do something like this:

1. On hover over the mapped area, Show a transparent black div, the same size as the image. (This makes the image darker)
2. Place another div on top of that, with the same dimensions as the image. (this contains the small map-sized container for the new image)
3. Place another div INSIDE of the last to be the same size and position as your mapped area. (This will contain the original image - not darkened)
4. Place the image again INSIDE of the last div and position it so it lines up with the original image.

This should show something like what you're talking about.

If it's more complicated than this, I'm sure we will ALL need an example and all of the outcomes of these images.  I don't think there's enough detail to give you a real answer.