# Darken an image on hover - twitter bootstrap 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following scheme set up using Twitter Bootstrap 3.0:
[image: test]
Now, when the cursor hovers over each tile, how do I darken the tile? I haven't made any changes to bootstrap.css. My custom styles.css is given below:

```
.row {
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

My html is as follows:

```
{% include 'buzzwire/header.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

    <br /><br />
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a href="/test-buzz"><img src="{% static 'img/buzzbutton.jpg' %}"/></a>          
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a href="/testing/test"><img src="{% static 'img/testbutton.jpg' %}"/></a>
       </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a href="/test-buzz"><img src="{% static 'img/buzzbutton.jpg' %}"/></a>
          <!--<a href="/test/about"><img  src="{% static 'img/about.jpg' %}"/></a>
          <a href="/test/contact"><img  src="{% static 'img/contact.jpg' %}"/></a>-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a href="/test-buzz"><img src="{% static 'img/testbutton.jpg' %}"/></a>          
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a href="/test-buzz"><img src="{% static 'img/testbutton.jpg' %}"/></a>          
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a href="/test/categories"><img src="{% static 'img/buzzbutton.jpg' %}"/></a>
       </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a href="/test-buzz"><img src="{% static 'img/testbutton.jpg' %}"/></a>
          <!--<a href="/test/about"><img  src="{% static 'img/about.jpg' %}"/></a>
          <a href="/test/contact"><img  src="{% static 'img/contact.jpg' %}"/></a>-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a href="/test-buzz"><img src="{% static 'img/buzzbutton.jpg' %}"/></a>          
        </div>
      </div>
        {% include 'buzzwire/footer.html' %}
```

I am pretty new to css and bootstrap. On hovering over the tile, either darkening it in general would do or turning it a shade darker of itself would also work (i.e. orange turns dark orange). Thanks for in advance for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to darken an image on mouseover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747637/how-to-darken-an-image-on-mouseover)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is going to be something that the bootstrap package contains, you'll have to reach out to other areas for your solution. Something to the effect of this should do it.

```
$j(function() {
    $j(".fadeover").hover(function() {
        $j(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.2
        });
    }, function() {
        $j(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    });
});
```

[Check this jsfiddle out](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/xbkK6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#pictureIdYouWantToChange').hover(function(){
      $(this).animate({
        'background-color':'DarkOrange'
});
});
```

You can give an ID to the element that you wish to change and when you hover over it
it will apply the animate function.  $(this) just means the item that's being hovered over.
You can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp) we have a bunch of colors.  Set the background color of the div to a light shade of red, and the when you hover over it pick a different color from that list.
If you choose to use a hex color value prefix it with a #
like 'background-color':'#abc123'

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple html:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 orange"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 yellow"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 orange"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 yellow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 yellow"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 orange"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 yellow"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 orange"></div>
    </div>
```

All you NEED is the hover selector in CSS:

```
div{
    height:40px;
}
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.yellow:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
.orange{
    background-color: orange;
}
.orange:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

However, this is a great opportunity to use less:

```
@yellow:yellow; //change here
@orange:orange; //change here

div{
    height:40px;
}
.yellow{
    background-color: @yellow;
}
.yellow:hover{
    background-color: darken(@yellow,10%);
}
.orange{
    background-color: @orange;
}
.orange:hover{
    background-color: darken(@orange,10%);
}
```

Doing it this way makes it easy to make changes and fine tune things.  You can also write your own function to essentially darken everything...

Check out and play with darken, shade, tint, and spin: http://lesscss.org/#reference

EDIT: Here's a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/XnPJA/