# jQuery Black Overlay on Hover

Tags: jquery, overlay

I'm trying to make my thumbnails have transparent black overlay on hover.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LCmsE

I kind of copied this thread;

[How to darken an image on mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747637/how-to-darken-an-image-on-mouseover)

But it doesn't seem to be working for me no matter what I do.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a number of bugs, but here's a working fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tkshg

The big fix: `$('this')` should be `$(this)`

Comment: Thanks, I can see it works on codepen, but for some reason it doesn't work on my site...