# How to darken an round image on mouseover?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I managed to make my image darken when the user hovers over it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1747655/3571997) answer. However my image uses the bootstrap `img-round` class this causes it to look like this,

[image: Dark borders]

```
<a href="#" class="darken">
   <img src="<?=$_SESSION['avatar']?>" alt="avatar" width="150px" class="img-circle">
</a>
```

Is it possible to remove those dark borders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** you can do this,

You can add the `img-round` class to the `a` tag. This way the gradient overlay has the same shape as the image.

[image: Removed dark borders]

*For some reason the border isn't sharp, I will edit answer once I find a solution.*